# What are the benefits of singleton views in a true MVC (desktop) application?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, singlepage

I'm a member of a team building a single-page Javascript application. I come largely from a web background (Struts, Spring, Rails, Sinatra, etc.), which I know has a different interpretation of the MVC pattern. One thing I've seen in Desktop MVC (which I believe applies to single-page Javascript applications) is that they use instantiable models and singleton controllers and views. That is, there might be `Company.Book`, `Company.recentlyPurchasedBooksController`, and `Company.recentlyPurchasedBooksView`. The controller keeps an instance of the model (or collection thereof) and the view updates itself as that model changes.

My team -- also being from a web background -- find this very "magical." They strongly prefer a workflow wherein the controller creates an instance of the view, populates it with the model, and renders it to a portion of the page.

I have a few objections with this, but I don't have any personal experience telling me that my objections actually *matter*. The first is that controllers shouldn't know about the DOM, and thus can't tell the view where to render. They argue that views should be instantiable ("what if you want multiple copies of the view on the page?"), to which I respond that they probably want a collection view in those cases.

Where can I find blog posts, books, references, *anything* that will help settle this debate? Will breaking the MVC pattern for the sake of developer comfort be a net-gain or net-loss over the long term?

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't use it myself*, [puremvc](http://puremvc.org/) has a javascript port of its MVC implementation which I have found very instructive to poke around in. It's clear separation of concerns, including the one you mention, controller-view knowledge, is beautiful, as is their object diagram.

*For one page javascript web and air apps I have been using [JavaScriptMVC](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/) which I have found to ease my development problems no end (although I don't use all of it, just the parts I like - VC).